# The component "collapse" of bootstrap in conflict with isotope filters

Tags: bootstrap-4, jquery-isotope

I have a website page where i use bootstrap for the layout grid and isotope because i need to filter my content (by years, etc).

Im using the "collapse" component of the bootstrap and when i still do not click in any of the buttons that are filtering my content with isotope, i can see properly the information that was hidden with collapse and than appears (please, see image 1[image1- its ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHXTB.jpg), image 2[image2- its ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV5oV.png), image 3[image3- its ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH2Ei.jpg) and image 4[image4 - click to apply filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSct7.jpg)), when the information appears the content above changes the position (on height) as its supposed to do.

But, when i click the buttons and isotope filters the content the grid changes - the layout on height is not respected (please see image 5[image 5 - layout grid its not ok after filter applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuo1i.png)) - and when i click to see the content hidden by collapse component by bootstrap the content overlap (please see image 6[image 6 - content overlapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o02O7.jpg)).

I already searched here at stack overflow, on github, and also on the website, specifically trying mansory column ( https://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html ) but its not working as expected.

I will be very grateful if anyone could help me out.

**Here i have a simple code to illustrate the issue:
codepen.io/sofiarf/pen/VJRrRb**

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Isotope layout after any DOM change.

Since you are using Bootstrap 4 to handle the collapse of the content, Isotope is not aware of those changes. So, after any of these changes, you need to call Isotope layout function.

Bootstrap 4 fires an event after hiding and showing content. Adding a listener to those events solves the issue:

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
   $('.grid').isotope('layout');
});
```

I have updated your CodePen with the answer.

```js
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 100
  }
});

var $collapse = $('.collapse');
var $container = $('#container');

$(".filter-colunaesquerda").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: '.colunaesquerda'
  });
});

$(".filter-colunadireita").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: '.colunadireita'
  });
});

$(".filter-all").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: '*'
  });
});

$collapse.on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">

  <a href="" class="m-5 filter-colunaesquerda">Coluna esquerda</a>
  <a href="" class="m-5 filter-colunadireita">Coluna direita</a>
  <a href="" class="m-5 filter-all">Todos</a>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mb-5">


      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item colunaesquerda">
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
            <div class="card card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
            </div>
          </div>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum quas, tempore alias libero minima inventore esse quam aperiam autem molestiae dolores quaerat delectus at ducimus dolorum provident quis porro placeat? </p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 mb-5">


      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item colunadireita">
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
            <div class="card card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
            </div>
          </div>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum quas, tempore alias libero minima inventore esse quam aperiam autem molestiae dolores quaerat delectus at ducimus dolorum provident quis porro placeat? </p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-6 mb-5">


      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item colunaesquerda">
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
            <div class="card card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
            </div>
          </div>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum quas, tempore alias libero minima inventore esse quam aperiam autem molestiae dolores quaerat delectus at ducimus dolorum provident quis porro placeat? </p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 mb-5">


      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item colunadireita">
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample4">
            <div class="card card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
            </div>
          </div>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum quas, tempore alias libero minima inventore esse quam aperiam autem molestiae dolores quaerat delectus at ducimus dolorum provident quis porro placeat? </p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample4" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button></div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>





<script src="/docs/4.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```